# Is there any elactic pool/scalability technique for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, scalability

I'm new about mongodb architecture. My manager asked me for shared mongodb cluster.
We are curious about scalability.

Consider a mongo db cluster have 5 nodes.  Database "X" located on shard A and shard B. Another database "Y" can be located to C, D and E nodes. Can we increase the number of nodes if we needed higher storage/CPU capacity for database X or Y?

We aren't cinsider only adding new nodes, in terms of needs, can we use node C for both database X and database Y?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By default, all databases will be spread across all of the shard in the cluster.

You can tag databases or chunks of collections to only be stored on specific shards, and you can retag these as necessary to move the data around.

See [Zones](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/zone-sharding/index.html#zones)

Comment: Thanks for reply. As I know, sharding keys for collections. So we have to specify zones for each collections of databases. Is there any default way to do like 'every collections in this database belong to this zone'?

Comment: Zone tags are based on the shard key, so each collection would need to be assigned.

Comment: You can set the primary shard for a database, which is where all un-sharded collections will be stored.